# How to prove this set of congruences involving various moduli?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider:

$x\equiv 6\pmod {13}$

$x\equiv 0\pmod {43}$

$x\equiv 10^n \pmod {41}$.

For x and n nonnegative integers.

Using Wolphram I found a set of solutions:

$x=903+22919\cdot s$ is one solution

Another is:

$14319+22919\cdot s$

let’s call the generic solution:

$d+22919\cdot s=x$, with d an integer depending on n.

How can I prove that d is either $\equiv 0\pmod {215}$ or $\equiv 129\pmod {215}$ or in only one case $\equiv 43\pmod{215}$? Or is the statement false?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde not x but d

Comment: You probably want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem, especially the section about "Computation" which contains an example. This should be enough for you to start by adapting the proof to your case !

Comment: You found the solutions of the CRT system for $\,n=0,1.\,$ You also need to find the solutions for $\,n=2,3,4\,$ since $\,10\,$ has order $5$ modulo $41$. You will find that they are not all of the form you presume. Why did you presume that form? Why are you working modulo $\,215?\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

If you first check the possibilities for $x\equiv 10^n \pmod {41}$ you will find that $x$ is congruent to one of $1,10,16,18,37$ modulo $41$.

You can now apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem to see that you require numbers of the form $43d+22919s$, where $43d\equiv 6 \pmod {13}$  and $43d\equiv 1,10,16,18,37 \pmod {41}$.

These conditions simplify to $d\equiv 8 \pmod {13}$  and $d\equiv 5,8,9,21,39 \pmod {41}$.

It should be straightforward now but ask if anything is unclear! The following answers should allow you to check if you have the right idea. These are the values for the $d$ in your post.

$$344,903,10965,14319,17114.$$